# Orchard CMS: Connect List content part to content item

Tags: orchardcms

I have been struggling with what I thought would be simple.

I have a content type called Supplier. This supplier has contact information containing two addresses, one for Correspondence Address and one for Visiting Address. The supplier has also several locations, like location north and location south. A location is also an address. So basically I have a content item Supplier with a lot of addresses and all of them with their own type.

Migration:

```
        public int Create() {
        //Creating the Location contentrecord, contentpart and contenttype
        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("LocationPartRecord", table => table
                                                                     .ContentPartRecord()
                                                                     .Column<int>("LocationsPartRecord_id")
            );

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("LocationPart", part => part
                                                         .Attachable(false)
                                                         .WithField("LocationName", f => f.OfType("TextField"))
                                                         .WithField("AddressLine1", f => f.OfType("TextField"))
                                                         .WithField("AddressLine2", f => f.OfType("TextField"))
                                                         .WithField("Zipcode", f => f.OfType("TextField"))
                                                         .WithField("City", f => f.OfType("TextField"))
                                                         .WithField("Country", f => f.OfType("TextField")));

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Location",
                                                     cfg => cfg
                                                                .WithPart("CommonPart")
                                                                .WithPart("LocationPart")
            );

        //Creating the Locations 'container' contentpart
        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("LocationsPartRecord", table => table
                                                                      .ContentPartRecord()
            );

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("LocationsPart", builder => builder.Attachable());

        //Creating the supplier. Specific supplier contentfields can be added later. Doing records, so I can add
        //datafields later that are not contentfields
        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("SupplierPartRecord", table => table
                                                                     .ContentPartRecord());

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("SupplierPart", part => part
                                                                                 .Attachable(false)
            );

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Supplier", builder => builder
                                                                                .Creatable()
                                                                                .Draftable()
                                                                                .WithPart("CommonPart")
                                                                                .WithPart("TitlePart")
                                                                                .WithPart("BodyPart")
                                                                                .WithPart("AutoroutePart", partBuilder =>
                                                                                                           partBuilder.WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.AllowCustomPattern", "true")
                                                                                                               .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.PatternDefinitions", "[{Name:'Supplier', Pattern: 'aanbieders/{Content.Slug}', Description: 'aanbieders/supplier-name'}]")
                                                                                                               .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.DefaultPatternIndex", "0"))
                                                                                .WithPart("SupplierPart")
                                                                                .WithPart("LocationsPart"));

        return 1;
    }
```

Models:
**LocationPartRecord and LocationPart **

```
public class LocationPartRecord:ContentPartRecord {
    public virtual LocationsPartRecord LocationsPartRecord { get; set; }
}

public class LocationPart:ContentPart<LocationPartRecord> {
    LocationsPartRecord LocationsPartRecord {
        get { return Record.LocationsPartRecord; }
        set { Record.LocationsPartRecord = value; }
    }
}
```

**LocationsPartRecord and LocationsPart (container)**
    public class LocationsPartRecord:ContentPartRecord {

```
    public LocationsPartRecord()
    {
        Locations = new List<LocationPartRecord>();
    }

    [CascadeAllDeleteOrphan]
    public virtual IList<LocationPartRecord> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class LocationsPart:ContentPart<LocationsPartRecord> {

    public LocationsPart() {
        Locations = new List<LocationPart>();
    }

    public readonly LazyField<IList<LocationPart>> _locations = new LazyField<IList<LocationPart>>();

    public IList<LocationPart> Locations {
        get { return _locations.Value; }
        set { _locations.Value = value; }
    }
}
```

From here I am stuck. I would like to see when Creating a new supplier, I get a screen containing all the content item fields for supplier and a list of locations, with the ability to create, delete or update a location.

I don't need the code to be spelled out, but a direction would suffice. Which drivers, controllers and views should I create. This is only for admin console. For frontend the locations need to be displayed and not edited.

Comment: I have same requirement please tell me which approach worked for you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there will be any way to get the functionality you're after without custom coding. As you have suggested, the comments module could be a good example to copy. The Controllers in the comments module are only to manage all of the comments in their own admin pages, separate to the content items they belong to. The edit / display of the comments is still provided through the drivers and handlers.

Using the Comments module analogy:

CommentsPart = AddressesPart - This would be added to your Supplier content type

CommentPart = AddressPart - This would be added to your Address content type

You could strip out a lot of the extra functionality that is included for managing comments and just copy the drivers, handlers, views and models for these two parts.

I have seen some gallery modules that may allow you to build these relationships through the admin interface, however I haven't used it myself:
http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Downplay.Mechanics

Comment: I think I will try it with your advice. When I strip the whole thing down it basically comes to the question how to attach an 'array' of a certain content part to a content type from the admin panel.

Comment: Downplay.Mechanics is in beta and hasn't been updated on the Orchard Gallery for over 18 months. The source on Codeplex has not been updated for 9 months. I mention this because Orchard is on v 1.6 now and at the time the code repository may be focused on 1.3. Was going to downvote, but the rest of your post is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

Address shouldn't be a part, it should be a field. This way, you can have more than one, and each can be named.

Comment: Hi I don't get your answer. An address consists of many fields and a supplier has many addresses. Can you elaborate?

Comment: A field in the Orchard sense. Please read http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Basic-Orchard-Concepts#ContentField A field can be a complex object.

Comment: I have read the documentation before and read it again:). Ok, let's say I create a field being a complex object. Still I don't know how to make it a repeating field. The number of locations is unknown upfront. Please take also a look at my updated question with my code. I am sorry to bother you about this.

Comment: No trouble. It wasn't clear that you wanted an undetermined set of addresses. If that's the case, then you could build a relationship in code (see http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-1-n-and-n-n-relations), or you could make address a content type and use a content item picker field. That would not require code, but would be slightly awkward in terms of UE.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this would be helpful (and the site appears to be down - but Google has a cached version if you are patient for it to load), but there is a good blog about exactly your situation. It's Skywalkers excellent [Web Shop](http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-1) series. I believe Part 8 contains the code related to multiple addresses (uses Address and Addresses). This seems to involve your problem, and the code may be what you need.

In case you have trouble getting to the site, there is also a [CodePlex](http://skywalkerwebshop.codeplex.com/) repository for the code. Additionally, Bertrand's [Nwazet Commerce](https://bitbucket.org/ems/nwazet.commerce) module might have similar code.